# Cannot set non-existant property PMD sonarqube plugin

Tags: maven, sonarqube, pmd

I have created a custom plugin for sonarqube version 4.5.1. This plugin contains a new custom rule, based on PMD. I have followed some examples (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins) for develop this plugin in correct way, but all time i build the project that I have to check with sonar, i have the same error: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set non-existant property 'maxAuthorisedMethodsCount' on Rule MaximumMethodsCountCheckRule*
My Sonar installation have also installed the *sonar-pmd-plugin v2.2* and *sonar-java-plugin v2.4*.
Below the code that generates error

**extensions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <rule>
    <key>MaximumMethodsCount</key>
    <name>Maximum Methods Count Check</name>
    <description>Massimo numero di metodi autorizzati per classe</description>

    <!-- path to definition -->
    <configKey>rulesets.xml/MaximumMethodsCountCheckRule</configKey>

    <!-- Default priority ("severity"). It can be changed while activating the rule in Quality profile -->
    <!-- Possible values are: INFO, MINOR, MAJOR, CRITICAL, BLOCKER. Default value is MAJOR -->
    <priority>MAJOR</priority>

    <!-- parameters available in administration console of Quality profiles -->
    <param>     
      <key>maxAuthorisedMethodsCount</key>
      <description>Numero massimo di metodi autorizzati per classe</description>
       <!-- default value is optional --> 
      <defaultValue>4</defaultValue>      
    </param>

  </rule>

</rules>
```

**rulesets.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">

    <description>
        sonar plugin rulesets
    </description>

    <rule name="MaximumMethodsCountCheckRule"
          message="Superato Numero massimo di metodi autorizzati per classe. Trovati {0} metodi!"
          class="alm.plugin.rules.MaximumMethodsCountCheck">

      <description>
        Numero massimo di metodi autorizzati per classe
      </description>

      <priority>3</priority>

      <properties>
        <property name="maxAuthorisedMethodsCount" description="Maximum number of methods authorised">
        </property>
      </properties>      
      <example>
        <![CDATA[
                //Troppi metodi!
                public void metodo1(){}
                public void metodo2(){}
                public void metodo3(){}
                public void metodo4(){}
                .....
                public void metodo14(){}
        ]]>
      </example>      
    </rule>  
</ruleset>
```

**MaximumMethodsCountCheck.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBody;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclaration;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.AbstractJavaRule;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.properties.IntegerProperty;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.sonar.api.Property;

public class MaximumMethodsCountCheck extends AbstractJavaRule {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private static final IntegerProperty propertyDescriptor = new IntegerProperty("maxAuthorisedMethodsCount", "Massimo numero di metodi", 0, 2, 4, 1.0f);

    @Override
    public Object visit(ASTClassOrInterfaceBody node, Object data) {    
        logger.info("---Analisi con MaximumMethodsCountCheck---");
        List<ASTMethodDeclaration> metodi = node.findChildrenOfType(ASTMethodDeclaration.class);
        if(metodi.size() > getProperty(propertyDescriptor)){            
            addViolation(data, node, ""+metodi.size());
        }
        return super.visit(node, data);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ALM-soanrqube-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>ALM-soanrqube-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>sonar-plugin</packaging>


  <name>SONARQUBE PLUGIN</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-java-plugin</artifactId>
            <type>sonar-plugin</type>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginClass>alm.plugin.PmdExtensionPlugin</pluginClass>
                    <basePlugin>pmd</basePlugin>
                    <pluginDescription>PlugIn per Sonar</pluginDescription>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- UTF-8 bundles are not supported by Java, so they must be converted during build -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

Anyone have any idea on how to fix the error ? Please Help! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `definePropertyDescriptor(propertyDescriptor)` in the constructor of your `MaximumMethodsCountCheck` class.

(I figured this out by looking at some of the provided rules which have properties, for example [NPathComplexityRule](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/codesize/NPathComplexityRule.java))